# MySQL Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

First of all, sorry for this being in Dutch, I doubt understanding the language is needed for this though.

whenever I Forward-Engineer, it gives me error 1452. The thing is, I am using existing parent table data to fill the child table.

[image: These are the two tables i'm having trouble with.]

[image: This] is the insert from the PARENT table, which is not empty as you can see.

[image: This] is the insert from the CHILD table, filled with existing data of PARENT table.

And finally the error I get when forward-engineering [image: here].

I've been stuck for so long, would really appreciate an answer. Hope I gave enough information (first time asking question).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer the description of your problem to be shown as text, not images. Why? We hope to build a searchable archive of questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql 1452 error refers to that you're trying to insert child records whose parent id(s) are not in the parent table.

try matching your columns with the following query.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ct.id 
FROM 
   child_table as ct 
   LEFT JOIN parent_table as pt ON ct.parent_id=pt.id 
WHERE 
    pt.id IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps!